# How do you write ten-person apartments? Ten-persons-apartment or?

Tags: hyphenation

How do you write ten-person apartments? Ten-persons-apartment or ?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Each ten-person apartment can accommodate ten persons.

Comment: The general rule is that you hyphenate the words composing a compound adjective, but not a noun.  But of course this is English, so there are exceptions.

Comment: According to [this table](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/16/images/ch07_tab01.pdf) (excerpted from the book _The Chicago Manual of Style_) you should write it like this: _ten-person apartment_. (See the 2nd page, 4th row)

Comment: @deadrat : You forgot to add "in accordance with the prophecy."

Comment: "I didn't really believe that it was a ten-person apartment until I noticed that it had that ten-person-apartment smell."

Comment: @Ricky ...So it has come to this.

Answer (score 0):

"I didn't really believe that it was a ten-person apartment until I noticed that it had that ten-person-apartment smell."